# Save U and V vector file as shape file (.shp)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, shapefile

I have four 2D array consist of u, v component of a vector and corresponding coordinates. I can draw these vector by ‘quiver plot’ and able to save as png, jpg etc. But I want to save this as a vector file (.shp, .evf etc). For understanding, I created two sample u and v vector and draw the result which I want to save as shapefile. I tried but didn’t find luck with pyshp python package.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

u = np.zeros(shape=(4,4))
u[0] = [0.0,0.5,0.4,0.1]
u[1] = [0.2,0.4,-0.2,0.3]
u[2] = [0.3,0.0,0.4,0.1]
u[3] = [0.6,0.4,0.2,0.3]

v = np.zeros(shape=(4,4))
v[0] = [-0.4,0.3,0.0,0.1]
v[1] = [0.1,0.3,0.2,0.4]
v[2] = [0.4,0.3,0.3,0.1]
v[3] = [0.0,0.1,0.3,0.2]

x,y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,3,4), np.linspace(3,0,4))

plt.figure();
plt.title('Velocity Field')
plt.xlim(-1,4)
plt.ylim(-1,4)
plt.quiver(x, y, u, v, color='r', scale = 1, angles = 'xy', units='xy', scale_units='xy') 
plt.show()
#plt.savefig('sample.png', dpi=150, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
```

Many thanks for any help/suggestion.

Comment: you want to save the arrows?

Comment: Yes, I want to save the arrows. I attached the sample .shp file with supporting files to open in ArcGIS, ENVI, QGIS or even in python, which is generated from u and v vectors. Can be download from

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1x9j47zPfOTFX49fwCGXMD4B1Upz4gy-L?usp=sharing

Thanks

Comment: you don't really save arrows as a shapefile because they're symbolizations of the data, not the data itself. you're kind of barking up the wrong tree here.

Comment: you really should make the quiver map in QGIS or whatever GIS software you're using directly http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/VectorFieldRenderer/

Comment: @Paul H Many thanks for your comment and suggestion. Can you please have a look on the file I uploaded in the previous comment?
So, you are right that arrow is a symbolization but in actual this arrow means a polyline with attribute table and arrowhead. So we can calculate the lenght and velocity from it.

Comment: I don't open random files from strangers on the internet. Feel free to edit the question to include a screen shot. Nonetheless, you shouldn't save a GIS file of your vector field's symbolization for display. You should configure your GIS software to display your vector field in a manner that accounts for the map's extent and scale.